# print recursive folders / files using ssh connecting ftp

Tags: recursion, ssh, ftp

I would like to print folder/file list (recursive). I can connect ftp server using ssh and can download using wget but before downloading I would like to print entire directory structure before downloading everything from server.

I have tried https://superuser.com/questions/790253/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-ftp-recursive-listing-to-a-local-file-with-windo but it didnt work.

Please suggest work around.

Thank you
Jessy

Comment: Are you writing some kind of script to automate this? Or are you doing it interactively? When you say it "didn't work", what _exactly_ did you do and what _exactly_ happened? Did you get any error messages? What did they say?

Answer (score 0):

I have found work around, What I did is using filezilla I have loaded all the files in queue and later exported that queue to retrive path.

Thank for your help

Jessy